# Schengen Visa: do I mention tourist spots in my travel itinerary?

Tags: schengen, germany

I am writing a detailed travel itinerary for Germany visa. Do I mention exact tourist spots that I'd go to? I haven't thought about that yet, so I have just mentioned "sightseeing". Is that okay?

[image]

Comment: I think naming cities and hotels will be enough. Any sane person would adjust the details according to weather, anyway.

Comment: I see you're also including a bit of time-travel? Better adjust the dates in the final two rows.

Comment: Keep it simple. They don't require those details

Answer (score 1):

The visa officials want to make a guess on what you are likely to do in your visit and use a series of questions for that. For  tourist not having detailed plans is the norm. Adding too many details may make them a bit suspicious although some tourist work out to the minutes where they will be.

List the cities and hotels if already known but no need to go into more detail.
If asked, in an interview or when crossing the border into the country you can name a few of the options.